# What order do threads run (execute) after being submitted to ExecutorService?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, thread-safety, filewriter

<strike>Is there a better way to make writing to files thread safe (for cases where the file may not be all the same in every thread) than synchronizing the method or the file writer? I read a few threads similar to this topic, but they seem to focus on one file as opposed to multiple files.</strike>

Ex. There are 20 threads that writes (meaning it uses a method that creates a a file writer to the file and then writes to it with a try-catch, etc) to file; 10 of the threads write to fileA, 5 threads write to fileB, 4 threads write to fileC, and 1 thread writes to fileD.

Synchronizing the method would not be efficient since threads that want to write to different files will have to wait for the previous thread to finish before it can proceed. I think synchronizing the file writer does pretty much the same or am I wrong?

If I were to have a separate thread thread (from the main application) that writes to a file, would they execute (run) in the order they were submitted to the ExecutorService with 1 thread?

In the main application, I would submit new threads to the ExecutorService (uses 1 thread). The threads would write to a file (using a write method that has the FileWriter synchronized from a Logger class). The threads would write to the file one by one because the FileWriter is syncrhonized and there is only 1 threads for the ExecutorService, which will prevent multiple writes to the same file at once. The question is will the threads write to the file in the order they were submitted to the ExecutorService? I know they start in the order they were submitted, but I am not too sure on the execution order.

Comment: I don't really see the point. Ultimately you will be limited by how fast you can write a line to a file. Adding queues and threads in front of that will make the sending threads go faster, but it will also use memory, and you can't let that happen indefinitely. You will have to use a bounded blocking queue to control that, and once you hit the bound, you will be back exactly where you were before but with a great deal of extra code to go wrong. Just synchronize on the output stream/writer.

Comment: @EJP When I did a simple test, I noticed that synchronizing the FileWriter instances wasn't what I wanted because even though they were writing to the same file, they were different FileWriter instances, which meant that they could all write to the same file at the same time. Also, synchronizing the method didn't help since they were all different instances. So the only way that this would work is if I have a Singleton, but that would mean only one thread can write to any file at a time. Does this sound correct?

Comment: @EJP I changed the question up a bit based on your response and decided to take a different route.

Comment: “*In the main application, I would submit new threads to the ExecutorService (uses 1 thread).*” — This sentence make no sense at all.

Comment: @Holger I used the wrong terms, but here is an example. ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1); executor.submit(new someRunnable); executor.submit(new someRunnable); executor.submit(new someRunnable); executor.submit(new someRunnable);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are mixing some things up which creates the confusion: First, `ExecutorService` is an interface that does not mandate a particular way how the submitted tasks (*not threads*) are executed. So it doesn’t make sense to ask how an `ExecutorService` will do a particular thing as it is not specified. It might even drop all tasks without executing anything.

Second, as already mentioned above, you are submitting *tasks*, not threads, to an `ExecutorService` whereas the tasks may implement `Runnable` or `Callable`.

Unfortunately there’s a design flaw in Java that `Thread` implements `Runnable` so you actually can pass a `Thread` instance to `submit()` which you should never do as it creates a lot of confusion for no benefit. When you do so, the common `ExecutorService` implementations will treat it as an ordinary `Runnable` invoking its `run()` method ignoring the fact completely that it is a `Thread` instance. The thread resource associated with that `Thread` instance will have no relationship with the thread actually executing the `run()` method (*if* the implementation ever calls `run()`).

So if you submit tasks implemented as `Runnable` or `Callable` to an `ExecutorService` you have to study the documentation of the particular implementation to learn about how they will be executed.

E.g. if you use [`Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadExecutor--) to get an implementation, its documentation says:

> Creates an Executor that uses a single worker thread operating off an unbounded queue. (Note however that if this single thread terminates due to a failure during execution prior to shutdown, a new one will take its place if needed to execute subsequent tasks.) **Tasks are guaranteed to execute sequentially, and no more than one task will be active at any given time**. Unlike the otherwise equivalent `newFixedThreadPool(1)` the returned executor is guaranteed not to be reconfigurable to use additional threads.

<sup>(emphasis by me)</sup>

So that would answer your question completely. Note that in this case you don’t even need `synchronized` within your task’s implementation as this `ExecutorService` already provides the mutual exclusion guaranty required for your tasks.

Comment: Thanks for this. Exactly what I need. I am glad to know that they execute sequentially.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the alternative of having a specialized file writer thread that is the only thread to write to the files. The other threads can safely add messages to a `java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue`. As soon as a thread has placed a message on the queue, it can get back to work.